# Text to Speech using iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, avaudioplayer

I am implementing an text to speech application. As my requirements I need to delay the output speech some time during the play. It is like follows,

My name is [5 seconds delay] James. like this. When the speech starts it needs to pause 5 seconds during the play. Is this is possible ? Please suggest

Comment: I am also want the solution of the same problem and also I want to speech to text conversion. if any one know any API or sample code them please let us know 
Thanks in advance

Comment: can u tell me is it possible to do text to spech conversion using open ears only ,,if yes tehn how to do it please give suggestion -ChandraSekhar

Answer (score 1):

have used OpenEars Libs personally .Does a good job and well documented (easy to set UP) and as far as i know there are no official sdk's available